# Last message in correspondence

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table of messages (sid = sending correspondent ID, rid = receiving correspondent ID, mdate = message date, mtext = message text) representing a correspondence among parties:

```
sid|rid|    mdate   |  mtext
---+---+------------+----------
 1 | 2 | 01-08-2014 | message1    <-- 1st m. in corresp. between id=1 and id=2
 2 | 1 | 02-08-2014 | message2    <-- 2nd m. in corresp. between id=1 and id=2
 1 | 2 | 04-08-2014 | message3    <-- last m. in corrensp. between id=1 and id=2
 2 | 3 | 02-08-2014 | message4    <-- not id=1 correspondence at all
 1 | 3 | 03-08-2014 | message5    <-- 1st m. in corrensp. between id=1 and id=3
 3 | 1 | 04-08-2014 | message6    <-- 2nd m. in corrensp. between id=1 and id=3
 3 | 1 | 05-08-2014 | message7    <-- last m. in corrensp. between id=1 and id=3
 5 | 1 | 03-08-2014 | message8    <-- last m. in corrensp. between id=1 and id=5
```

requested MySQL query should return for one correspondent (being sender or receiver) only correspondence with last message (sent or received) with other parties. So from previous table of messages this query for correspondent with id=1 should return last correspondence messages (last sent or received):

```
sid|rid|    mdate   |  mtext
---+---+------------+----------
 1 | 2 | 04-08-2014 | message3
 3 | 1 | 05-08-2014 | message7
 5 | 1 | 03-08-2014 | message8
```

How to make such a query for MySQL?

Comment: @Strawberry: Question looks fine to me?  Or have you seen to many [tag:greatest-n-per-group] questions today

Comment: Brian's answer is incorrect I think, see counter example in my comment to his answer.  Joseph interprets your question differently and his query will return 2 rows at most.  Me and Fabricator use the same logic, but I think Fabricator's answer is more elegant, so I would accept that.

Comment: Thanks Andomar for your expertise and generosity recommending somebody else answer for accepted one but could you recommend the best answer taking into account the execution price (this message table will have a lot of messages) taking into account inner selects, full table scan, group by, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

group by sid if rid=1 or rid if sid=1 to find max date, then join:

```
select a.*
from messages a
join (
  select if(sid=1, rid, sid) id, max(mdate) d
  from messages
  where sid = 1 or rid = 1
  group by id) b on ((a.sid=1 and a.rid=b.id) or (a.sid=b.id and a.rid=1)) and a.mdate = b.d;
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cedb8f/3)

Comment: +1 Original approach with `if(sid=1, rid, sid)`!  Your aliases could be clearer though, who abbreviates a message as `a`, a date as `d`, and a subquery as `b` ?

Comment: This query does work! (although Fabricator likes obfuscating it, but it doesn't matter - maybe he works for SAP)

Comment: @Andomar I guess I do :-(

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that there are no messages with the exact same timestamp between two correspondents, you can use a filtering join:

```
select  *
from    messages m
join    (
        select  case when sid > rid then sid else rid end r1
        ,       case when sid <= rid then sid else rid end r2
        ,       max(mdate) as max_mdate
        from    messages
        where   1 in (sid, rid)
        group by
                r1
        ,       r2
        ) as filter
on      m.sid in (filter.r1, filter.r2)
        and m.rid in (filter.r1, filter.r2)
        and m.mdate = filter.max_mdate
```

[Example on SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26dfb2/3/0)

Comment: Will that consider the sid 1, rid 2 a seperate row from sid 2 rid 1 (same discussion, but the values in sid/rid are reversed)?

Comment: @Twelfth: You're right!  Updated the query so it groups on the respondents in descending order.

Comment: I figured a case statement to have the low ID first would be the way to go...I guess at the end of it, the conversation will show as sid being the low ID and RID being the high ID regardless of who is sending the message.  I think it works, +1

Answer (score 0):

Does the following join work for you:

```
SELECT m.*  
FROM messages m
INNER JOIN
(SELECT
    MAX(
        CASE
            WHEN sid = 1 THEN mdate
            ELSE NULL
        END
    ) max_sdate,
    MAX(
        CASE
            WHEN rid = 1 THEN mdate
            ELSE NULL
        END
    ) max_rdate
FROM messages
WHERE sid = 1 or rid = 1
) max_dates
ON (m.sid = 1 AND mdate = max_dates.max_sdate) OR (m.rid = 1 AND mdate = max_dates.max_rdate);
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26dfb2/1)</kbd>

Comment: Wouldn't this show two messages from a single conversation?  The last one sent and the last one received?

Comment: No, it gets the required result perfectly. Basically, the inline view gets the maximum date for the received message and separately, the latest date for the sent message. Then, these dates are used to look up the messages from the table.

Comment: If I read your query right, it returns the latest received and sent message (at most two.)  I think the OP is looking for the last message per conversation.  Btw, you can omit `else null` in a `case`, that's the default.  For example `case when 1=0 then 1 end` evaluates to `null`.

Comment: It works if he only wants to see messages from 1.  I'd imagine he'd want to have this come back with all conversations and not just for user 1 at one point.  Can this be adapted to show all conversations and the max date associated?

Comment: Sorry this query does not work generally! It returns just one id=1 sender and one id=1 receiver rows. Take into original table sid,rid,mdate,mtext values(5,1,'03-08-2014','message8') and it will not be returned as one of messages in correspondence with id=1!